# how to put tracker on Edit box in android

Tags: android, passwords

I m new in android 
I have an edit box. where we have to enter the password in EditBox for sign up Screen.
I want that, when user click on it it highlight the EditBox and then character cross the limit of 6 character then a green tick mark will show in the right of EditBox.
if you can give me code
Here is my code

I will be very thankful of you
Thanks in advance
Gaurav Mehta

Comment: have you tried some thing?

Comment: else if ((pass.length() < 6)) {
if ((pass.length() >= 6)) {
LinearLayout l5 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l5);
l5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "i m don",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
AlertDialog.Builder nnn = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUp.this);
nnn.setTitle("Alert")
.setIcon(R.drawable.tick)
.setMessage("Your password is too Short,Choose minimum 6 digit password !.")
 .setPositiveButton("OK",
 new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(
   DialogInterface dialog,
    int which) {
  
    }
 })
.show();
  }

Comment: yes sir 
this else if part is correct
when i put if block in elseif then it not check the if block

Comment: in xml file for edit box drawable/highlight is used so from where i get this image ?

Comment: its not an image. its drawable file. I wrote that ** you need to create file in drawable directory** and it is xml file which contains drawable information.

Comment: Please mark accepted and upvote if it helped. So future searcher can get benefits from it. :)

Comment: In my application I will implement google map example My One Confusion 1. When i directly run the application the map will run perfectly 2. while i can make sign apk (make Key Store file and related to key Store Apk) then the map will not work For this problem i am tried so many ideas like 1. Create an another and another API KEY of my app related to package 2. Put extra permission in Android Manifest File (Lastest Manifest permission are given Below) please Help Me I am in trouble. Thanks..

Comment: Map View requires API keys until you are using unsigned APK. But whenever you sign your application and use it, there is no requirement of API key with your desktop specific.

Comment: ok sir now i m able to solve this problem thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create a `hightlight.xml` in drawable directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/highlight_bg" android:state_focused="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal_bg" android:state_focused="false"></item>
</selector>
```

2) Create `normal_bg` in drawable directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF" />
</shape>
```

3) Create `highlight_bg` in drawable directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" > 
    <solid android:color="#FFFF0000" />
</shape>
```

4) In your layout you need to create with following parameters.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/highlight"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" >
    </EditText>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgTick"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
        android:src="@drawable/tick"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Put any **tick** image in your drawable directory.

5) Put following code to get length listener on password field.

```
EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(s.length()>6){
            findViewById(R.id.imgTick).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            findViewById(R.id.imgTick).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
});
```